# How to set a multiindex with multiple dates in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, multi-index

I have the following dataframe `df`:

```
Datetime1              Datetime2             Value
2018-01-01 00:00       2018-01-01 01:00      5
2018-01-01 01:00       2018-01-01 02:00      1
2018-01-01 02:00       2018-01-01 03:00      2
2018-01-01 03:00       2018-01-01 04:00      3
2018-01-01 04:00       2018-01-01 05:00      6
```

I want to set a multi index composed of `Datetime1` and `Datetime2` to further proceed with the data resampling and interpolation (from 1 hour to 30 minutes frequency).

If I do `df.set_index(["Datetime1","Datetime2"]).resample("30T").ffill()`, then it fails.

Desired output:

```
Datetime1              Datetime2             Value
2018-01-01 00:00       2018-01-01 01:00      5
2018-01-01 00:30       2018-01-01 01:30      5
2018-01-01 01:00       2018-01-01 02:00      1
2018-01-01 01:30       2018-01-01 02:30      1
...
```

Comment: It looks like MultiIndex is not the right tool for you. It's for a hierarchical index, i.e. with groups. See here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html
What are you trying to achieve? Is `Datetime2` always 1 hour offset from `Datetime1`

Comment: What is your desired output? Consider having single datetime index but set its `frequency` (judging by your data it would be "1h"). Then resample the dataframe.

Comment: @Joooeey: Yes, `Datetime2` is always 1 hour offset from `Datetime1`. I just need to resample the data from 1 hour frequency to 30 minutes frequency, maintaining the same offset. For `Value` I wanted to apply `ffill()`.

Comment: @michcio1234: The desired output is the same dataframe but resampled from 1 hour to 30 minutes frequency. How can I set a single datetime index with frequency?

Comment: Please see the desired output in the update.

Comment: @Fluxy check out this: `idx = pd.date_range(start="2021-01-01", freq="1h", periods=5); df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(5)}, index=idx); df.resample("30min").ffill()`, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is one hour difference is possible create `MultiIndex` after `resample` with add `1H` to new `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df = df.set_index(["Datetime1"])[['Value']].resample("30T").ffill()
df = df.set_index([df.index.rename('Datetime2') + pd.Timedelta('1H')], append=True)

print (df)
                                         Value
Datetime1           Datetime2                 
2018-01-01 00:00:00 2018-01-01 01:00:00      5
2018-01-01 00:30:00 2018-01-01 01:30:00      5
2018-01-01 01:00:00 2018-01-01 02:00:00      1
2018-01-01 01:30:00 2018-01-01 02:30:00      1
2018-01-01 02:00:00 2018-01-01 03:00:00      2
2018-01-01 02:30:00 2018-01-01 03:30:00      2
2018-01-01 03:00:00 2018-01-01 04:00:00      3
2018-01-01 03:30:00 2018-01-01 04:30:00      3
2018-01-01 04:00:00 2018-01-01 05:00:00      6
```

Or:

```
s = df.set_index(["Datetime1"])['Value'].resample("30T").ffill()
s.index = [s.index,s.index.rename('Datetime2') + pd.Timedelta('1H')]

print (s)
Datetime1            Datetime2          
2018-01-01 00:00:00  2018-01-01 01:00:00    5
2018-01-01 00:30:00  2018-01-01 01:30:00    5
2018-01-01 01:00:00  2018-01-01 02:00:00    1
2018-01-01 01:30:00  2018-01-01 02:30:00    1
2018-01-01 02:00:00  2018-01-01 03:00:00    2
2018-01-01 02:30:00  2018-01-01 03:30:00    2
2018-01-01 03:00:00  2018-01-01 04:00:00    3
2018-01-01 03:30:00  2018-01-01 04:30:00    3
2018-01-01 04:00:00  2018-01-01 05:00:00    6
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: jezrael, if Datetime1 and Datetime2 would need to be as 00:00 and 00:30 instead of 00:00 and 01:30, then the approach would be similar, right? Just Datetime2 would be shifted by 30 minutes instead of 1 hour.

Comment: @Fluxy - exactly you are right. change `+ pd.Timedelta('1H')` to `+ pd.Timedelta('30Min')`

Answer (score 1):

The multi-index is not meant for a double-index but for a hierarchical (grouped) index. [See the docs.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html) You said in the comments, that `Datetime2` is always offset by 1 hour. That means it's probably fastest to recalculate it:

```
df.set_index("Datetime1","Datetime2").resample("30T").ffill()
df["Datetime2" = df.index + pd.Timedelta(1, "hour")
```